# Convert a dask series to a list of values

Tags: python, dask

Is there a way to convert a series from a dask dataframe to a list, in order to iterate over that?

Until now I have:

```
ddf = dd.read_csv(MY_FILE)
s = ddf.iloc[:,[0]]
r = s.compute()
r.a_column.values
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Will this list fit into memory?

Comment: Sure, my problem is that is taking a lot of time to compute a large dataset, so my question is more focus on a 'native' way in Dask to iterate over a series without compute.

Comment: @CrisHernandez do you think suggested solution is optimal? I am curios because you accept the Ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's preferable to avoid iterating over rows whenever possible (and use vectorized operations instead), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas). However, if the operations performed on elements of the row are independent of neighbouring rows, then the easiest thing to do in `dask` is `.map_partition`:

```py
def myfunc(df):
    # apply row operations assuming df is a pandas df
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # do something
        something = 'some_value'
    return something

r = ddf.map_partitions(myfunc)
```

Comment: I created a list to append the values inside the for loop, aimed to return that list. But, how could I get the values of that list which is representing a dask object?

Comment: Hmmm, how are you going to use the list afterwards? (is it going to be a parallel operation also or not?)

Answer (score 0):

how about using `inline for` sentence? You can make new iterable object

you can get the values of Dataframe using `values` attribute.

```py
ddf = dd.read_csv(MY_FILE)
s = ddf.iloc[:,[0]]
r = s.compute()
print([i[0] for i in r.values])
```

Comment: I got that. But, is there a way to take a Dask Series and transform that into a list of values, without doing compute previously?

Comment: In my knowledge, the dask dataframe is lazy operation. it means the dask dataframe has schema but no data, itself. So if you want to get data from file(etc.), then you should use the `compute()` function that is action(load and execute)  function.

Comment: I understand. Thanks mate. I think need to dig deeper in documentation.